# Trying to Convert Entire Project to ARC with SDWebImage

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a strange error when trying to convert to ARC. I have only one error: "SDWebImage is ARC only. Either turn on ARC for the project or use -fobjc-arc flag".  The error is happening in my SDWebImageCompat.m file here:

```
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
#error SDWebImage is ARC only. Either turn on ARC for the project or use -fobjc-arc flag
#endif
```

I am confused. I am trying to convert to ARC. Ive never had build errors with SDWebImage before, only now that I am trying to convert my whole project to ARC am I getting this error. The error does not occur when I build the project, only when I try to convert to ARC from the refractor. Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: How is the SDWebImage loaded? You must have definitely used a compiler option in Build phases. Remove the arc options from therefor specifically using SDWebImage.

Answer (score 0):

Try new version of SDWebImage, all you need - it's add particular .framework file and it's already in ARC. Remove SDWebImage, convert your project the add .framework. It works perfect for me!